# Click on Edit button from Table using protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

Application is developed in Angular Js and there report can be view in  table format and In table, last column is to edit the data.

I am not able to click on Edit Link . so help me out .
I used following code:

```
element(by.id("table_id")).getText().then(function(text){

    element.all(by.repeater("taski in allTask")).getText().then(function(text1){

        console.log(text1);

        link =element(by.className('editClr ng-scope')).all(by.tagName('td')).get(6).all(by.tagName('a'));
        link.click();


    });

 });
```

Attaching a Screen shot :
[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Also, can you provide URL?

Comment: element(by.repeater("taski in allTask").row(0)).getText().then(function(text){
  element(by.linkText('Edit')).click();
});

now i am using this inside "element(by.id......" so its giving me an err that more than one web-element found and its open only 1st row edit link .but if i wrote row(3) still its open 1st row edit link. so i want to locate specific in 3 rd row edit link.

help me out to solve it!

Comment: Can you give URL?

Comment: Not possible Kapil

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
function clickEditbyRowIndex(rowIndex) { // rowIndex >=0
    element.all(by.css('table#table_id > tbody > tr > td > a.editClr'))
   .get(rowIndex).click();
}

function clickEditbyTaskId(taskId) {
   element(by.css('table#table_id > tbody'))
  .element(by.xpath('./tr[td[.="'+taskId+'"]]'))
  .element(by.css('a.editClr'))
  .click();
}
```

Comment: I tried it using clickEditbyRowIndex function and its working fine
thank you! :)